# how to check whether the dataSnapshot null on Flutter Firebase (Realtime) Database plugin

Tags: flutter, firebase-realtime-database

I am using this [flutter Database plugin](https://pub.dev/packages/firebase_database).

```
firebase_database: ^7.1.1
```

I cannot find much documentation about it and no other answers solving my issue.

I need to verify that the child exists in the database before processing the result.

**In this situation the child not exists, and am trying to check**

```
    await FirebaseDatabase.instance
            .reference()
            .child('classrooms')
            .child(classroomId)
            .once()
            .then((DataSnapshot? data) {
             if(data == null)
             { 
                print('no data');
                return;
             } 
             print('This works');
     }
```

1. The **no data** statement is not printing
2. still **This works** printing even if it is null.

So the data is not null, but when I try to access the data.key or data.value it shows this error

**CODE**

```
.then((DataSnapshot? data) {
  if (data!.value == null) {
    print('data is null');
    return;
  }
```

**RESULT**

```
    flutter: data is null
    [VERBOSE-2:ui_dart_state.cc(186)] Unhandled Exception: Null check operator used on a null value
#0      DBController.fetchClassroom package:tajweed/controller/db_controller.dart:189 <asynchronous suspension>
#1      Classrooms.fetchClassroom.<anonymous closure> package:tajweed/providers/classrooms.dart:23 <asynchronous suspension>
```

I found some answers like check dataSnapshot.exists() or dataSnapshot.hasData() etc but no function are attached to the dataSnapshot object.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look at the docs for [`Query.once`](https://pub.dev/documentation/firebase_database/latest/firebase_database/Query/once.html) it actually returns a `Future<DataSnapshot>` and not a `Future<DataSnapshot?>`.  That because when you request data from the database, you **always** get a `DataSnapshot`.

If you want to know whether data actually exists at the location, you should check whether the snapshot has a value with [`DataSnapshot.value`](https://pub.dev/documentation/firebase_database/latest/firebase_database/DataSnapshot/value.html).

So:

```
.then((DataSnapshot data) {
     if(data.value == null)
     { 
        print('no data');
        return;
     } 
     print('This works');
}
```

Comment: Actually you answer helped me! Thanks a lot. I used the `DataSnaptshot?` because I referenced this example. https://github.com/FirebaseExtended/flutterfire/blob/master/packages/firebase_database/firebase_database/example/lib/main.dart They are used it with .get() methiod